# Email is not being sent from Node server

Tags: handlebars.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send an account verification email to user. The codes seems alright but I dont know why the email is not getting sent to the users mail even though the new user is created successfully in the database. I am  using handlebars to create the templates as I will be creating a password reset email too.

here is my code

```
import nodeMailer from "nodemailer"
import handlebars from "handlebars"
import fs from "fs"
import path from "path"

export async function sendEmail(email, subject, payload,templates){
    try {
      // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
      const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
        host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD, 
        },
      })
      transporter.verify().then(console.log).catch(console.error)
  
      const source = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,templates), "utf8");
      const compiledTemplate = handlebars.compile(source);
      
      const options = () => {
        return {
          from: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
          to: email,
          subject: subject,
          html: compiledTemplate(payload),
        }
      }
  
      // Send email
      transporter.sendMail(options(), (error, info) => {

        if (error) {
          return error
        } else {
          console.log("Email sent successfully")
          return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message:"Email sent successfully"
          })
        } 
        })
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
```

and here is where I am calling the sendEmail function in the registerUser controller.

```
export async function registerUser(req,res){

    try{
        const {email, password, userRole} = req.body;

    // Validation
  if (!email || !password ) {
    res.status(400).json({
        message:'Please include all fields'})
  }

  // Find if user already exists
  const userExists = await userModel.findOne({ email })

  if (userExists) {
    res.status(400).send({
        message:'User already exists'})
  }
  // CREATING USER

    /// function to generate accesstoken
    const tokens = jwt.sign({email},process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "1d"
       })
       
    const user = await userModel.create({
        email,
        password,
        userRole: "user",
        token:tokens
    })
    
    const link = `${process.env.BASE_URL}/user/verify/${user._id}/${user.token}`
    sendEmail(user.email,"Account Verification",
    {email: user.email,link: link,}, 
    "../templates/accountVerification.handlebars")
        

    if (user){
        res.status(200).json({
            message:'Registration Successful',
            user
        })

        
    }else{
        res.status(400).json({
            message:"Registration unsuccessful"
        })
    }
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error logged?

Comment: no please, no error is being logged.

Comment: The new user gets created but no email is sent,I tried to even log something from that part that the email is send but that also dont get logged to the console.

Comment: Instead of returning the error - `return error` - log the error - `console.error(error)`.

Comment: I have logged the error to the console but it does not show it